# Syntax Error Shell-Script: Saving stat output into Variable

Tags: shell

The following (reduced) shell-script runs fine on my mac with mojave (10.14.6), but I get an error message OS Yosemite (10.10.5)

```
DB_FULL_PATH=/Volumes/path

find $DB_FULL_PATH -type f| while read f; do
    < <(stat -f %Sm -t "%m %V %d" $f) read -s MONTH WEEK DAY
    echo $MONTH $WEEK $DAY
done
```

The error:

```
test.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
test.sh: line 17: ` < <(stat -f %Sm -t "%m %V %d" $f) read -s MONTH WEEK DAY '
```

Comment: what shell are you running? are you running bash?

Comment: @KamilCuk How do I find out? I'm a total beginner, trying to get an old script to work.

Comment: for example `echo $BASH` or `echo $0`

Comment: `echo $BASH` => /bin/bash, `echo $0` => test.sh. When I try `bash test.sh` there is no error.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you very much. `bash test.sh` just works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<(...)` is a bash extensions available on bash. Make sure you run your script under bash interpreter. Make sure that the shebang is bash, like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: Thank you very much!